# Why is replaced Fragment popped back again?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragmentmanager

In my App I have a `MainActivity` where I start a `CalcActivity` which includes two consecutive Fragments. I inflate those Fragments successively by

```
fun replaceFragment(resId : Int, fragment : Fragment){
    this.supportFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.replace(resId, fragment)?.addToBackStack(null)?.commit()
}
```

So in my `CalcActivity`:

1. I inflate `CalculationFragment` with `replaceFragment(R.layout.frag_calc, CalculationFragment())`
   collect data and calculate a result in the first fragment.
2. When I have a **result** I call a callback from `CalculationFragment` in my Activity
3. In that callback (back in `CalcActivity`) I `replaceFragment(R.layout.frag_result, ResultFragment())` to show my results.

This is working so far, **BUT**
whenever I backpress it goes back to `CalculationFragment` ?!

I was exprecting to go back to the MainActivity..

> MainActivity
>
> +-> CalcActivity
>
> ```
>        +-> CalculationFragment
>        +-> ResultFragment
> ```

How can I go back to MainActivity?

Comment: Don't use callbacks when send result from an activity to an activity. Use `setResult()` and `onActivityResult()` (there is some difficulty with fragments). Also check in every activity's `onCreate()` for `if (savedInstanceState == null)` before adding a fragment. And I suppose, your code is not sufficient.

Comment: Can you post some more code ?

Comment: @CoolMind I've used callback from ChildFragment to ParentActivity..

Comment: @NoamSilverstein, a callback can be lost if your activities recreate. So I recommend to use `onActivityResult()`. It is a bit more difficult, but you can avoid some callback problems. Also I don't understand what activity calls what callback. Show in your code, please.

Comment: @Pritish How about an example project: https://www.file-upload.net/download-13557879/BotNavCleanMvp.zip.html

Comment: @CoolMind not the exact, but a similar example. https://www.file-upload.net/download-13557879/BotNavCleanMvp.zip.html